# Orthogonal Matrix with a specific row

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal, orthogonality

I have an assignment with the following question:

```
Does an Orthogonal Matrix exist such that its first row consists of the

 following values:
```

($1$/$\sqrt{3}$, $1$/$\sqrt{3}$, $1$/$\sqrt{3}$)

```
If there is, find one.
```

I know I can solve this question with the Gram Schmidt algorithm, but it includes a lot of complicated calculations.

Is there any other way to prove this statement without the Gram Schmidt algorithm?

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: There is another way.  You should be able to show that each row (column) of an orthogonal matrix is orthonormal to the other rows (columns) of the matrix.  That fact should be enough to answer the original question.

Comment: @Louis, can you please elaborate, as I amnot sure how to prove that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I misread the question!  I managed to read $1, {\sqrt{3}}$  instead of $1/{\sqrt{3}}$.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2241414/constructing-a-4-times4-orthogonal-matrix-having-frac121-1-1-1-as-its.

Comment: An orthogonal matrix will have mutually perpendicular rows of unit vectors so as long as the vector is a unit vector you're have sufficient conditions for the existence of such a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

$(\frac1{\sqrt3},\frac1{\sqrt3},\frac1{\sqrt3})$ is a unit vector, so you're off to a good start.  (That is, there is such a matrix.)

Next just choose a perpendicular vector, and normalize it.  So, say, $(\frac1{\sqrt2},-\frac1{\sqrt2},0)$.

Finally you need a vector perpendicular to the first two, and again of unit length.   The cross-product will produce such a vector.  Or, looking at the first two, I think I can produce one out of the blue.  Namely, $(\frac1{\sqrt6},\frac1{\sqrt6},-\frac2{\sqrt6})$.  You can easily check that the dot products with the other two vectors are zero.  And it has unit length.

So one such matrix is:  $$\begin{pmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt3}& \frac1{\sqrt3}& \frac1{\sqrt3}\\\frac1{\sqrt2}&-\frac1{\sqrt2}&0\\\frac1{\sqrt6}&\frac1{\sqrt6}&-\frac2{\sqrt6}\end{pmatrix}$$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose two vectors which are orthogonal to $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$ and make sure they are also orthogonal to each other.

Vectors orthogonal to $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$ lie in the plane $x+y+z=0$.

For example choose $(1,-1,0)$ to be the second row of your matrix.

Now you need a third vector which satisfies the equations:

$$x+y+z=0 ~~~ \text{[is orthogonal to}~\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)]$$
$$x-y=0 ~~~ \text{[is orthogonal to}~(1,-1,0)]$$

Any such vector can form the third row of your orthogonal matrix.

Comment: One way to find a 3rd vector is to take the cross product of the first two vectors.

Answer (score 0):

i answered a similar question before, but i don't know how to make a link to that.

so i will repeat the way to find a symmetric reflection matrix whose row is your unit vector. reflect $((1,1,1)^T/\sqrt 3$ to $(1,0,0)^T$ on the mirror in the direction of their bisector $a = (1 + \sqrt 3, 1, 1)^T.$  form the matrix $q = 2aa^T/a^Ta - I;$ that will satisfy your requirement.