# Constructing a $4\times4$ orthogonal matrix having $\frac{1}{2}(1,1,1,1)$ as its first row

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, orthogonality, orthonormal

> Construct an orthogonal matrix having $\frac{1}{2}(1,1,1,1)$ as its first row.

Let $\bf A$ be the required matrix.

Looking at the first row, I can just construct a Helmert matrix which is necessarily orthogonal.

$$\mathbf A=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{4}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{4}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{4}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}&0&0\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}&\frac{-2}{\sqrt{6}}&0\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}&\frac{-3}{\sqrt{12}}\end{pmatrix}$$

> Is this a unique answer? Can the row vectors of $\bf A$ form different orthonormal bases of $\mathrm V_R(\mathbf A)$, the row space of $\bf A$, keeping the first row intact?

I have to find $3$ vectors which are orthogonal to the $1$st row and also orthogonal to each other. Just using the definition and taking the $2$nd, $3$rd and $4$th row of the required matrix as $(x_1,...,x_4), (y_1,...,y_4)$ and $(z_1...,z_4)$ respectively I get from $\bf AA'=I$,

$$\sum_{i=1}^4x_i=\sum_{i=1}^4y_i=\sum_{i=1}^4z_i=0$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^4x_i^2=\sum_{i=1}^4y_i^2=\sum_{i=1}^4z_i^2=1$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^4x_iy_i=\sum_{i=1}^4x_iz_i=\sum_{i=1}^4y_iz_i=0$$

However I don't think this is the right way to proceed, searching for solutions by trial and error.

> I would like to know the right approach for this particular problem and also in general, the easiest way to construct an orthogonal matrix given any one of its rows/columns.

Comment: There are many ways to contruct such matrices but the rows are indeed orthogonal. The easiest way would probably be to do a Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization if you have heard about it.

Comment: Can't you just replace a row with its negative? That shouldn't kill any of the needed zeros and also not the norm 1 (as here you have squares...). I suppose that there are other ways in which a orthonormal basis is not uniquely determined by a single vector, however, -1 is the easiest I see right now...

Comment: @mathreadler Yes I have heard about it. Do I have to take the 1st row vector and extend it to an orthonormal basis using Gram-Schmidt process?

Comment: You don't have to do anything. But it is one way to do it if your only requirement is that the resulting matrix should be orthogonal.

Answer (score 3):

Let $B$ be any $3$-by-$3$ orthogonal matrix and $C$ be the block matrix
$$C=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&B}.$$
Then $CA$ is an orthogonal matrix with the same first row as $A$;
you get all such matrices that way, so there's a lot of them!

My favourite example is the scaled Hadamard matrix
$$\frac12\pmatrix{1&1&1&1\\1&1&-1&-1\\1&-1&1&-1\\1&-1&-1&1}.$$

Comment: Could you expand on justifying your second statement and also how to obtain the scaled Hadamard matrix so that it is orthogonal? Is it possible to obtain such an orthogonal matrix for any order?